# Replacing Strings with a number in it without a for loop

Tags: java, regex, parseint

So I currently have this code;

```
for (int i = 1; i <= this.max; i++) {
    in = in.replace("{place" + i + "}", this.getUser(i)); // Get the place of a user.
}
```

Which works well, but I would like to just keep it simple (using Pattern matching)
so I used this code to check if it matches;

```
System.out.println(StringUtil.matches("{place5}", "\\{place\\d\\}"));
```

StringUtil's matches;

```
public static boolean matches(String string, String regex) {
    if (string == null || regex == null) return false;
    Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    return compiledPattern.matcher(string).matches();
}
```

Which returns true, then comes the next part I need help with, replacing the {place5} so I can parse the number. I could replace "{place" and "}", but what if there were multiple of those in a string ("{place5} {username}"), then I can't do that anymore, as far as I'm aware, if you know if there is a simple way to do that then please let me know, if not I can just stick with the for-loop.

Comment: Do you mean you just need to obtain the number after `place`? `s = s.replaceAll(".*\\{place(\\d+)}.*", "$1");`? Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: Is `replaceAll()` available?

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: You'd need a callback. Global Find: `(\{place(\d+)\})`, Replace with array lookup for $2 if found, otherwise replace with the match $1.

Comment: @stribizhev You should add as an answer since it solve the OP's problem

Comment: @JorgeCampos: I did not know, there was no user tag :( I am adding the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> then comes the next part I need help with, replacing the {place5} so I can parse the number

In order to obtain the number after `{place`, you can use

```
s = s.replaceAll(".*\\{place(\\d+)}.*", "$1");
```

The regex matches arbitrary number of characters before the string we are searching for, then `{place`, then we match and *capture* 1 or more digits with `(\d+)`, and then we match the rest of the string with `.*`. Note that if the string has newline symbols, you should append `(?s)` at the beginning of the pattern. `$1` in the replacement pattern "restores" the value we need.